# conditional sequence validate from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am having an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]`.

Now i am creating a function that returns if the input is valid sequence or not, but i have some exceptions that need to be resolved.

1. Input will always be in sorted manner.
2. Function should return true or false.
3. input length should be > 3 and < 14. from (numbers 1 to 13)

Examples.

- [1,2,3] - true
- [1,2,3,4,5] - true
- [8,9,10,11] - true
- [11,12,13] - true

Exceptions.

- [1,11,12,13] - true
- [1,8,9,10,11,12,13] - true
- [1,4,5,6] - false
- [1,3,4,5] - false

exception is if there is `1` and there is sequence i want to return true. there is cycle of 1-13, 13 is attached to 1

here is what i have tried,(not working for exceptions)

```
function isvalid(array) {
    if (array.length < 3) return false;
    return array.every((e, i) => i === 0 || (e - 1 === array[i - 1]));
}

console.log(isvalid([1,11,12,13])) // false , should return true
```

Comment: Why in your example exceptions  **[1,8,9,10,11,12,13]** shouldn't be false?

Comment: there is cycle of 1 - 13, its attached

Comment: [1,11,12,13] => as there is cycle, 1-13

Comment: @AshishKamble didnt got you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a staged approach by looking to the first index or to all other an perform a check wich is related to either the next element or the last one.

It check, if either

- the *previous* item plus one is equal the the actual item, or
- the actual item plus one is equal to the *next* item, or
- the index is either zero or one and the *first* element is `0` and the *last* one of the array is `13`.

```js
function isConsecutive(array) {
    return array.every((v, i, a) =>
        a[i - 1] + 1 === v ||
        v + 1 === a[1] ||
        i < 2 && a[0] === 1 && a[a.length - 1] === 13
    );
}

console.log(isConsecutive([1, 2, 3]));                 //  true
console.log(isConsecutive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));           //  true
console.log(isConsecutive([8, 9, 10, 11]));            //  true
console.log(isConsecutive([11, 12, 13]));              //  true
console.log(isConsecutive([1, 11, 12, 13]));           //  true
console.log(isConsecutive([1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])); //  true
console.log(isConsecutive([1, 4, 5, 6]));              // false
console.log(isConsecutive([1, 3, 4, 5]));              // false
console.log(isConsecutive([2, 11, 12, 13]));           // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: its return [2,11,12,13] => true. should return false, as no cycle of 1-13

Comment: it needed another check.

Comment: @NinaScholz Well done, can you explain what .every() function does

Comment: it calls for every element of the array the callback and if all calls returns a truthy value, it returns true. it works like an universal quantifier (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)).